# Preventing overwrite of file upload and MySQL record through form?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have a submission system set up and I'd like to have it so no duplicate entries can be submitted. If one is submitted, the ORIGINAL record and file upload is kept (not overwritten). Also, if it exists I'd like the form to display an error to the user. Here's my upload.php (referred to in the HTML form).

*upload.php*

```
<?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$extension = explode(".", $_FILES['upload']['name']);
$extension = $extension[count($extension)-1];
$target = "uploads/";
$target = $target . $_POST['snumber'] . "." . $extension;

//This gets all the other information from the form and prevents SQL injection
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$upload=($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$snumber=$_POST['snumber'];
$grade=$_POST['grade'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Table` VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$snumber', '$grade', '$email', '$target')") ;

//Writes the upload to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
//Tells you if its all ok
echo "Your submission ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " was successful and we have received your submission. Your result will be sent to $email ";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: Combined suggestions from below, here's updated code however now I'm getting a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /path/to/upload.php on line 32`

New upload.php

```
<?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$extension = explode(".", $_FILES['upload']['name']);
$extension = $extension[count($extension)-1];
$target = "uploads/";
$target = $target . $_POST['snumber'] . "." . $extension;

//This gets all the other information from the form and prevents SQL injection
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$upload=($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$snumber=$_POST['snumber'];
$grade=$_POST['grade'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

//Checks if submission already exists
if(file_exists($target))
{
    echo "This submission already exists. Please check that you have entered all values correctly. If this is an error please contact support";
}
else
{
    //Now that file doesn't exist, move it. 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target);
    //MYSQL CONNECTION
        mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ;
        mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()) ;
    //MYSQL Entry
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table (fname, lname, snumber, grade, email, target) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($fname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($lname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($snumber)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($target)."')")

    echo "Your submission was successful and we have received your portfolio. Your marks will be sent out to $email.";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the table structure looks like?

Comment: Yeah, inserts like that are bad ideas. If you modify the table by adding a column somewhere in the middle it will break this query. Example, if you wanted to gather middle initials you might place that column between fname and lname. Then the query fails. Should be ("INSERT INTO `Table` (`fname`, `lname`, `snumber`, `grade`, `email`, `target`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($fname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($lname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($snumber)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($target)."')")

Comment: Added it into original code, however getting SYNTAX error.

Comment: @VedPetkar don't forget the ";" after the mysql_query("INSERT INTO  ....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're storing the target in your database, so you can either check the database to see if that file already exists or you can use php's file_exists() function.

DB you obviously run the query before that insert statement and make your conditional based off the results.

Otherwise,

```
if(file_exists($target))
{
    echo 'error';
}
else
{
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target);
   // do success things here
}
```

file exists may require the full path. If it doesn't work right away see if prepending $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] helps.

Comment: And then do the `INSERT` inside the `else` case. Otherwise you will insert the record in the database twice

Comment: I see, so after placing the `INSERT` (SQL Statement) into the else case, it'll only add the row AFTER the file exists check is done?

Comment: @VedPetkar The best way will be to verify if `move_uploaded_file` is successful. If `move_uploaded_file` returns TRUE then add to the database.

Comment: Attached new code to include those changes. However, now it checks if the file exists or not (if it does then it gives error) but if it doesn't it will continue. However, it never checks if the actual move was successful like the original code. What would I do to add that in?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by applying an ajax query before submitting the form and the file

```
var param = "action=testfile&dirpath=" + dirpath + "&file=" + filename;

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: 'combi/testfile.php',
       data: param,
       success: function(data) {
            test data .... if OK submit.
       }
```

In testfile.php you test for the file and echo out the data

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'testfile'){
    $msg = '';
    $basedirpath = $_GET['dirpath'] . "/";

    if(file_exists($basedirpath . $_GET['file'])) {
        $msg = 'exists';
    }
    echo $msg;
}
```

$msg is returned in the data in the ajax call.